# The <Thumbnail /> is not showing

Tags: javascript, next.js

This is my Results.js

[image: 1]

This is my Thumbnail.js

```
`import React from "react";

const Thumbnail = ({ result }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Thumbnail</h1>
    </div>
  );
};


export default Thumbnail;`
```

This is in my index.js

`<Results results={results} />`

When I want to call Thumbnail in Results.js, why the  in Results.js not showing ?

Comment: maybe the results array does not contain any data.. check that

Comment: Please make sure to post code as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Where does `results` come from in `index.js`? Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

`results` most likely doesn't have any data. If it did, React would loop through the array and render out a `Thumbnail` for each item in the array.

To test this, set a simple variable in your file to an array of, let's say, 3 items.
`const items = [1,2,3];`

Then, use this item to map over the `Thumbnail` component.

```js
export default function Results() {

...
const items = [1,2,3];

return (
<div>
  {items.map(item => (
    <Thumbnail result={item} />
  )}
</div>
)
```

You should see then three rendered out `Thumbnail` components